# Migrate virtualmachine from VirtualBox 6.1 to VirtualBox 7.0

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm trying to migrate a Windows 10 VM from VirtualBox 6.1 to a new laptop using VirtualBox 7.0.

The VM boots up on the new laptop, but crashes soon after, and before I can don any meaningful diagnostics.

I've tried exporting the VM using "Open Virtualization Format 1.0" (ova file), and also copying the vdi, vbox, etc files.  Both methods give the same results.

- The Old system:  Kubuntu 22.04, VirtualBox 6.1
- The New system:  Kubuntu 23.10, VirtualBox 7.0

Comment: Why not upgrading the Kubuntu 22 VBox version to 7 then migrate the VM?